# iOS - ID of nearby Places with Google Places API export to database

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api

In my app I need find nearby places from my current location and export ID these places to my database. It's all. I use this code below with Google Places API and then I see marked nearby places from my current location on the map. Then I want to get ID these places. How can I get this?

```
- (IBAction)pickPlace:(UIButton *)sender {
  CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.5108396, -0.0922251);
  CLLocationCoordinate2D northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude + 0.001, center.longitude + 0.001);
  CLLocationCoordinate2D southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude - 0.001, center.longitude - 0.001);
  GMSCoordinateBounds *viewport = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:northEast                                                                   coordinate:southWest];}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have copied Googles example code for their place picker. Is that correct? You can not get results from the placekicker. However if you always want to get places around the user, you can look at [this](https://developers.google.com/places/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_places_client.html#a8c3d13a740c821c35c67f795b0032b29), specifically "currentPlaceWithCallback:". The list you get back should be a list of GMSPlaces around you (also containing the ID).

If that is not good enough or if you want to be able to search around another location there is [this](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search?hl=en) web API